# Later in the movies Harry Potter was able to just flick his wand and cast a spell but earlier they had to say the spell to and then flick their wand?

Tags: harry-potter

In Harry Potter the were able to just flick their wand and cast a spell does that mean all they had to do was think of what spell they wanted to cast in order to cast it?

Comment: I suggest you read the books, nonverbal spells were a big theme in 6.

Comment: Note that while the original question was focused on the movies, the answers heavily cited the explanation from the books.

Comment: My mistake thank you:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the sixth book, "Half-Blood Prince," the students were taught how to use nonverbal spells, i.e. to cast spells without saying the words out loud. It does boil down to thinking about the spell they wanted, but as we see from Harry's difficulty in mastering it, it's quite a bit more nuanced than that.

Comment: Good answer, and correct except that the sixth book is "Half-Blood Prince"; Deathly Hallows is the 7th.

Comment: Oops, right. Corrected.